# A thinner béarnaise?

Tags: sauce

I've been using Julia Child's béarnaise recipe---2 tbl reduction, 3 egg
yolks, 4 oz clarified butter---, which produces a very thick sauce.  Is
this just how it's supposed to be, or is there a non-heretic way of
making it thinner?

Comment: How thick is "very thick"?  It's supposed to be as thick as commercial mayonnaise.

Comment: @FuzzyChef, yes, I suppose it's about as thick as that.

Comment: Well, that's the desired texture. If you want it thinner ... whip/cook it less.

Comment: If you make your Béarnaise (or other Hollandaise derivative) over a bain-marie, and everything is clean, you can slacken it with a splash of hot water from there,.

Answer (score 1):

The thickness is coming from the ratio of oil to water. Like mayonnaise, bearnaise is an oil-in-water emulsion, and will get thinner the more water is in it. (Consider the relative thickness of moist sand and mud; the butter in the bearnaise is like the sand.) Adding a bit of hot water will work well to thin it, but do so a bit at a time, stirring well afterwards, as a little bit of water will go a long way.

Comment: do you mean a butter-in-water emulsion?

Comment: @Toothrot Yes, butterfat is a type of oil.

Answer (score -1):

Every sauce is different in viscosity. To test the 'perfect' viscosity, the classic test for it is to see if it coats the back of a spoon smoothly and evenly. To solve your problem, I will suggest that you thin it with water or stock; and don`t use butter or oil.

Comment: A sauce made without butter would not be a bearnaise.

Comment: After you have made a bearnaise sauce , with 'butter', and the sauce is "thick" then one should use water or stock to "THIN" it.